# Linux ping command on read-only system

Tags: linux, ping, readonly

I'm working on a read-only system. Everytime I run the ping command it seems to get stuck for a few seconds until somehow it manages to output the expected message. When I switch the system back to read-write mode ping works perfectly fine.
I suppose the command is trying to write on a file and this is the reason for this delay. 
How can I find what file is writen?? My idea is to move this file to a tmpfs in ram. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: you could use [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find out which files are accessed

Comment: thanks. very insightful. I didn't know it

Answer (score -1):

I think it has to do with dns. Because when I try to ping using the ip address it works well. Previously I was trying to check the system internet connection pinging to www.google.com. Now what I do is pinging directly to 8.8.8.8, which is google public dns server. Thanks